# Stop Google Dictionary from throwing error on double click on Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Every time I double click on the canvas I have set up, I get this error:

```
Error in event handler for 'undefined': IndexSizeError: DOM Exception 1 Error: Index or size was negative, or greater than the allowed value.
    at M (chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js:17:154)
    at null.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js:19:417)
    at chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js:1:165
    at <error: illegal access>
    at Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:356:21)
    at Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:342:27)
    at Event.dispatch (event_bindings:362:17)
    at Object.chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnMessage (miscellaneous_bindings:273:22)
```

Which I believe is Google Dictionary. How do I prevent this? I have prevent default setup already like this:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();}, false);

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();}, false);
```

Unfortunately neither seem to have any effect, thanks for your help!

Edit: should add this is in Chrome

Edit: Just discovered it was specific to Chrome Version 28.0.1500.71, doesn't seem to effect earlier versions.

Comment: If you referring to this [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-dictionary-by-goog/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja?hl=en), why not just disable/remove it?

Comment: I'm worried about people who have it enabled using my site

Comment: How about a fiddle or a link to your site so we can get a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

instead of mousedown mouse up try using

```
canvas.addEventListener('dblclick', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();}, false);
```

in jquery its working so it should work using js

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html

Comment: No good, but I discovered that the error is specific to Chrome 28, could it just be a bug?

Comment: Couldn't hurt to file a bug if it started happening in Chrome 28. http://crbug.com/new